# GTK fill last element of FlowBox to end

Tags: c++, gtk3

I am having a (vertical) GTK `FlowBox` that has multiple children. All but the last are having no fixed size and are just filling the space their child control needs. The last element is in a `GtkScrolledWindow` and supposed to fill the remainder of the `GtkFlowBox`. I have tried several layout options but none of them makes the last child fill the remainder of the `GtkFlowBox`.

The things I have tried:

- Setting vertical alignment to `Fill` for the `GtkFlowBoxChild`, the `GtkScrolledWindow` and its child `GtkTreeView`
- Setting the `Expand Vertical` to `TRUE`for all the controls mentioned above

Is it possible to have an element of the `GtkFlowBox` fill the remainder of the box?

I am using GTK version `3.22.30`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use a regular `GtkBox` instead of a `GtkFlowBox` and make all but the last elements vertically aligned to the start.